# Entity Framework- The File Exists

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

I am using Nuget command update-database -verbose. It has been working but now when I run the command I get

> System.IO.IOException: The file exists.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
>      at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.ConfigurationFileUpdater.Update(String configurationFile)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade..ctor(String migrationsAssemblyName, String contextAssemblyName, String configurationTypeName, String workingDirectory, String configurationFilePath, String dataDirectory, DbConnectionInfo connectionStringInfo)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>   The file exists.

What file is it looking for? I tried to Clean the solution and rebuild it but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

From [This Blog](http://blog.jtbworld.com/2008/12/systemioioexception-file-exists-and.html)

> The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if it is used to create more than 65535 files without deleting previous temporary files.
>
> The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if no unique temporary file name is available. To resolve this error, delete all unneeded temporary files.

Looks like you need to go to your temp directory and delete some files.

Check your  "C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp"  directory of the account the software is running under (I assume your user name). It could also be in "C:\Windows\temp"

Another [Blog Entry](http://morten.bravonet.no/path-gettempfilename-causes-the-file-exists-exception) with a similar explanation.

Comment: This worked. Ran Ccleaner. 6 gb of temp files cleaned out. I was able to update the edmx model from the db after. Thanks! +1